# Inserir registro no banco ao clicar em div x

Tags: php, ajax

Como posso inserir um registo ao banco de dados ao clicar em uma div x

Tentei usar ajax mas não conseguir fazer a função

Tenho a função

```
$status = "on";
db::Query("UPDATE bdc SET status='$status'");
```

Queria inserir essa função ao clicar em uma div div X

Comment: Edite com o código já feito por você

Comment: Tenho só a função pra inseir no banco.

Comment: Criei um imput com um onclick, mas depois a função ajax não consegui fazer

Comment: Você precisa fazer o javascript, detectar o click na div e acionar o ajax para atualizar os valores com o php.

Comment: Entendi tudo thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seu link:

```
 <a href="#" id="atualiza">Atualizar</a>
```

E o seu Javascript (supondo que você utiliza JQuery)

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "atualizar.php",
  data: { status: "on"}
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Atualizado!" );
  });
```

No seu arquivo atualizar.php:

```
function atualizar($status){
db::Query("UPDATE bdc SET status='$status'");
}

if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'status')){
$status = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'status');
atualizar($status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para isso terias de utilizar *ajax*, utilizando *javascript puro* ou então *jquery*, e adiconar um esctutador de eventos a essa div. Contudo, não vejo grande utilidade em fazer isto com uma *div*, e ainda mais desta forma.

Neste exemplo vou utilizar *jquery* porque não tenho as melhores condições à minha disposição.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // mouseover, mouseout, leave
    $("#click").on('click', function(){
        var rando = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); // gerar numeros entre 1 e 100
        $.post('upd.php',{status: rando}, function(i){
            $("#demo").html('Retorno: ' + i);
        });
    });
  });
```

Isto aí é a parte do *jquery*, utilizei o evento *click* para não ter complicações, e também é meio incómodo processar requisições sempre que o mouse passa sobre uma div, o que provavelmente vai estar sempre a acontecer. Comentei os rentantes eventos.

Nos em requisições com o *ajax* podes sempre escolher entre *$.post, $.get, ou mesmo o $.ajax*.

- $.post e $.get (sem muita configuração);
- $.ajax (mais opções de configuração, tanto para *get* como *post*).

Para o *html* terias algo assim:

```
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="click"></div>
```

E isto para dispor as divs uma acima da outra:

```
<style type="text/css">
  div {display:block;}
  #click {width:100%; height:20px; background-color:#204a87; content:"OI";}
</style>
```

E por último, para o script *php* podias fazer algo assim:

```
session_start();

$data = isset($_POST['status']) && !empty($_POST['status']) ? (int) $_POST['status'] : "indefinido\n";

// Restantes verificações para $data...

if(isset($_SESSION['status']) && !empty($_SESSION['status'])){
    echo $_SESSION['status'];
} else {
    $_SESSION['status'] = $data;
    echo $_SESSION['status'];
}

session_destroy();
```

Neste exemplo usei sessões para ilustrar como seria a troca dos valores dessa mesma variável, para o caso de dos valores de *status* serem diferentes a cada requisição. Para uma consulta onde tem o tratamento das variáveis de sessão colocarias a consulta *SQL*, ficando assim:

```
$status = isset($_POST['status']) && !empty($_POST['status']) ? (int) $_POST['status'] : "indefinido";

// Restantes verificações para $status...

db::Query("UPDATE bdc SET status='{$status}'");
```